# unix shell: reverse search problem

Tags: shell, unix, search

I want to do a reverse search in unix shell. The Ctrl-R gives me the opportunity to specify the search string. The problem is that the command does not give me "enough time" to specify the string. Example: I want to reverse-search for "global". I enter the characters but as soon as I enter the 'g', it returns a result.

How can I specify a string of arbitrary length?

Thanks you,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about bash (for example) just keep typing -- the result updates as you type.

Answer (score 0):

from: http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/courses/FurtherUse/index.html

> This is incremental searching; as you
>   type each letter the most recent
>   matching command (being displayed) may
>   suddenly change. The shell will beep
>   if you type something that causes the
>   search to fail.

Comment: Thanks to all, I didn't realize that the reverse-search was not working because the search string was not found in the history. The reason for that is that I was convinced that the string was in the history because I had set my HISTFILESIZE to 20000 in the .bashrc file. I just realize one minute ago that the setting does not work (echo $HISTFILESIZE returns 500). Don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Just keep typing.  It's doing an "incremental search", meaning it will keep refining its search as you type.

Comment: That's what I thought but it does not always work. I just realized that it's not "working" when the search is unsuccessful. Thanks a lot!